# How can I uninstall the FTDIUSBSerialDriver?

Tags: macos, driver

How can I uninstall the FTDIUSBSerialDriver and FTDIUSBSerialDriverInstaller from my MacBook Air with Yosemite? They are shown in System Information → Software → Installations.

The files are highlighted in blue below:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

First, find out if the package is installed, and it's name:

```
pkgutil --pkgs | grep -i ftdi
```

It should output:

```
com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver
```

Then get a list of files:

```
pkgutil --files com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver
```

In my case, this was the result:

```
Library  
Library/Extensions  
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext  
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents  
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/Info.plist  
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/MacOS  
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/MacOS/FTDIUSBSerialDriver  
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/Resources  
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/English.lproj  
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings  
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature  
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
```

Then simply delete the files in question:

```
sudo rm -r /Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext
```

And follow it up with "forgetting" the package:

```
sudo pkgutil --forget com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver
```

Comment: This answer still works in 2018.

Comment: Hm, I'm following these steps but the device still shows up as an interface in the Mac's Network Prefpane.  I'm wondering if there's anything additional I need to do to uninstall.  Screenshots here: https://github.com/mavlink/qgroundcontrol/issues/8789#issuecomment-638526815

Comment: have you tried simply removing it from the list of networks with the minus button? Does it keep coming back? Does it also exist in the list of interfaces when adding a new interface? Did you try a reboot? (sorry, just had to check)...

Answer (score 4):

Answer from codebender itself here:
http://feedback.codebender.cc/knowledgebase/articles/861399-how-to-uninstall-the-drivers-installed-by-codebend

> Unistall FTDI drivers
>   In order to uninstall the FTDI drivers follow the steps below:
>
> Open a terminal and type:
>   `cd /System/Library/Extensions/`
>   Verify that the .kext file is present:
>   `ls | grep FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext`
>   Output should be:
>   `FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext`
>   Then type:
>   `sudo rm -R FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext`
>   Verify that the .kext file has been removed:
>   `ls | grep FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext`
>   Output should be empty.
>   After you should remove the files stored in receipts folder:
>   `cd /private/var/db/receipts/`
>   Find the enties:
>   `ls | grep FTDI`
>   Output should be: `com.FTDI.ftdiusbserialdriverinstaller.FTDIUSBSerialDriver-2.pkg.bom  com.FTDI.ftdiusbserialdriverinstaller.FTDIUSBSerialDriver-2.pkg.plist com.FTDI.ftdiusbserialdriverinstaller.postflight.pkg.bom com.FTDI.ftdiusbserialdriverinstaller.postflight.pkg.plist com.FTDI.ftdiusbserialdriverinstaller.preflight.pkg.bom com.FTDI.ftdiusbserialdriverinstaller.preflight.pkg.plist`
>   Remove each one of the files of the above list:
>   `sudo rm -rfilename`

Answer (score 2):

The kext is located here:

```
/System/Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext
```

Delete the kext, then delete the relevant receipts:

```
/Library/Receipts/ftdiusbserialdriver.pkg
                  ftdiusbserialdriverinstallerPostflight.pkg
                  ftdiusbserialdriverinstallerPreflight.pkg
```

Make sure you've got a backup.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `pkgutil` to forget installations?  Depending on when the installation was made it might only show up in the database. I've got three related installation packages: com.FTDI.ftdiusbserialdriverinstaller.FTDIUSBSerialDriver-2.pkg,
com.FTDI.ftdiusbserialdriverinstaller.postflight.pkg,
com.FTDI.ftdiusbserialdriverinstaller.preflight.pkg (pkgutil --packages | grep serial). None of them show up in /Library/Receipts. pkgutil will allow you to 'forget' them, see the man page. Use kextstat to determine if loaded, kextunload to unload if the driver is.