# Problem uninstalling FTDIUSBSerialDriver driver

Tags: macos, driver, kernel-extensions

I am trying to uninstall the FTDIUSBSerialDriver from my Mac. When checking System Information, I find two installations that I would like to remove.

[image: System Information screenshot - two FTDIUSBSerialDrivers listed]

I tried following this step-by-step guide here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/300774/459711

I can list several packages belonging to `com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver`, but when trying to remove them as described in the step-by-step guide, I get a `No such file or directory` error. I pasted the console output below.

How can I remove these?

Thanks a lot for the help!

```
user@MBP ~ % pkgutil --pkgs | grep -i ftdi
com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver
user@MBP ~ % pkgutil --files com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver
Library
Library/Extensions
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/Info.plist
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/MacOS
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/MacOS/FTDIUSBSerialDriver
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/Resources
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/English.lproj
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature
Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
user@MBP ~ % sudo rm -r /Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext
Password:
rm: /Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext: No such file or directory
```